# Using AngularJS, how can I match items from two separate ng-repeats?

Tags: angularjs

Using AngularJS, I am creating a table that is pulling data with two web requests.
Each web request has it's own ng-repeat in the HTML, `ng-repeat="user in users"` and `ng-repeat="app in apps"`. Right now all existing apps are showing in every repeat of `user`. What I'd like to do is some kind of match, lookup, or filter and only show apps that the user is associated with. So, when `user.Title == app.Title`.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <div class="ProfileSheet" ng-repeat="user in users">
      <h3 class="heading">User Profile</h3>
      <table id="Profile">
        <tr>
          <th>User</th>
          <td>{{user.Title}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <td>{{user.FirstName}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <td>{{user.LastName}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Job Title</th>
          <td>{{user.JobTitle}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Emp ID</th>
          <td>{{user.EmployeeID}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Officer Code</th>
          <td>{{user.OfficerCode}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Email</th>
          <td>{{user.Email}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Telephone</th>
          <td>{{user.WorkPhone}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Fax Number</th>
          <td>{{user.WorkFax}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Location Description</th>
          <td>{{user.LocationDescription}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Mailstop / Banking Center #</th>
          <td>{{user.Mailstop}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <br>

      <h3 class="heading">User Applications</h3>
      <div style="border:3px solid #707070; padding-right:12px;">
      <h4 style="padding-left:5px;">User Applications</h4>
      <table id="Apps">
        <tr id="AppsHeading">
          <th>Application</th>
          <th>User ID</th>
          <th>Initial Password</th>
          <th>Options / Comment</th>
          <th>Setup Status</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="app in apps">
          <td>{{app.Application.Title}}</td>
          <td>{{app.Title}}</td>
          <td>{{app.InitialPassword}}</td>
          <td>{{app.OptionsComments}}</td>
          <td style="border-right:3px solid #707070;">{{app.SetupStatus}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize']);
var basePath = "https://portal.oldnational.com/corporate/projecthub/anchormn/associates"
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $q){
    var supportList;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $scope.getAdminList();
        $scope.getAppsList();
  });

    // $scope.selectedIdx = -1;
    // $scope.showResults = false
    $scope.prepContext = function(url,listname,query){
        var path = url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/items" + query;
        console.log(path);
        return path;
    }
    $scope.getAdminList = function() {
    supportList = $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: this.prepContext(siteOrigin+"/corporate/projecthub/anchormn/associates","User Administration","?$orderBy=LastName"),
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
      }
    }).then(function(data) {
      //$("#articleSection").fadeIn(2000);
      console.log("adminlist", data.data.d.results);
      $scope.users = data.data.d.results;
    });
  };

    $scope.getAppsList = function() {
    supportList = $http({
      method: 'GET',
      // url: this.prepContext(siteOrigin+"/corporate/projecthub/anchormn/associates","User Applications","?$select=Title,InitialPassword,OptionsComments,SetupStatus,Application/Title&$orderBy=Application&$expand=Application"),
            url: this.prepContext(siteOrigin+"/corporate/projecthub/anchormn/associates","User Applications","?$select=Title,InitialPassword,OptionsComments,SetupStatus,Application/Title,ParentUserLink/ID&$orderBy=Application&$expand=Application,ParentUserLink"),
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
      }
    }).then(function(data) {
      //$("#articleSection").fadeIn(2000);
      console.log("appslist", data.data.d.results);
      $scope.apps = data.data.d.results;
    });
  };
});
app.config([
    '$compileProvider',
    function($compileProvider){
        $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrom-extension|javascript):/)
    }
]);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can **1)** Create a pipe (I recommend it less) and **2)** Mutate the array and group the desired apps per user before applying ng-repeat

Comment: Option 2 of mutating the array sounds far simpler to implement.

Comment: It is easier to demonstrate how to accomplish this if you share your controller code.

Comment: @JoeHawkins Updated with JS.

Answer (score 1):

*There's a lot of extraneous code in the controller. For the purposes of this answer I removed it. Also I understand that users and apps are related by a property called `Title` but the name was confusing me - forgive me if the data doesn't make sense.*

**Suggestion:** Only use `$`(jQuery) where strictly necessary. Angular provides a lot of functionality that replaces jQuery functionality. Instead of using `$.ready` like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $scope.getAdminList();
    $scope.getAppsList();
});
```

wait to bootstrap your application until the document is ready using the following code:

```
(function () {
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
    });
})();
```

Then you don't have to burden the controller with the responsibility of waiting until the document is loaded. *Note: `ng-app` was removed from the markup.*

**Suggestion:** Use `$q.all()` to wait for multiple promises to resolve. `$q.all()` will wait until all promises resolve to call `.then()`. This helps to ensure that all data is available when you start to use it.

**Suggestion:** Only assign properties and functions to `$scope` if they will be used by the view. I removed the functions that are not used by the view from the `$scope` object.

#### How does it work?

When the controller loads, we use `$q.all()` to invoke and wait for `fetchAdminList()` and `fetchAppsList()` to fetch data from an API. Once each API request resolves we unwrap the data in `.then()` callbacks and return it (read more on promise chaining to understand what happens when a value is returned from `.then()`). When both promises resolve, we store the data on `$scope` to make it available to the view. We also pre-compute which applications each user can use and store that data in `$scope.userApps` to make it available to the view.

I did not have access to the APIs you are fetching data from. I substituted `$http` calls with an immediately resolving promise using `$q.resolve()` and static data. When you are ready just replace `$q.resolve(...)` with the original `$http(...)` calls in the fetch functions.

Run the snippet to see it in action.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

(function () {
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
    });
})();

var USERS = [
    {
        Title: 'Software Engineer',
        FirstName: 'C',
        LastName: 'Foster',
        EmployeeID: 1
    },
    {
        Title: 'Software Engineer',
        FirstName: 'J',
        LastName: 'Hawkins',
        EmployeeID: 2
    },
    {
        Title: 'CEO',
        FirstName: 'Somebody',
        LastName: 'Else',
        EmployeeID: 3
    }
];

var APPS = [
    {
        Application: { Title: 'StackOverflow' },
        Title: 'Software Engineer'
    },
    {
        Application: { Title: 'Chrome' },
        Title: 'Software Engineer'
    },
    {
        Application: { Title: 'QuickBooks' },
        Title: 'CEO'
    }
]

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $q) {
    $q.all({
            users: fetchAdminList(),
            apps: fetchAppsList()
        })
        .then(function(result) {
            // Store results on $scope
            $scope.users = result.users;
            $scope.apps = result.apps;

            // Pre-compute user apps
            $scope.userApps = $scope.users.reduce(
                function(userApps, user) {
                    userApps[user.EmployeeID] = getUserApps(user.Title);
                    return userApps;
                },
                []
            );
        });

    function fetchAdminList() {
        return $q.resolve({ data: { d: { results: USERS } } })
            .then(function (data) { return data.data.d.results; });
    }

    function fetchAppsList() {
        return $q.resolve({ data: { d: { results: APPS } } })
            .then(function (data) { return data.data.d.results; });
    }

    // Get a list of apps that apply to user title
    function getUserApps(userTitle) {
        return $scope.apps.filter(function(app) {
            return app.Title === userTitle;
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>

<div>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

        <div class="ProfileSheet" ng-repeat="user in users">
            <h3 class="heading">User Profile</h3>
            <table id="Profile">
                <tr>
                    <th>User</th>
                    <td>{{user.Title}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <td>{{user.FirstName}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <td>{{user.LastName}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Job Title</th>
                    <td>{{user.JobTitle}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Emp ID</th>
                    <td>{{user.EmployeeID}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Officer Code</th>
                    <td>{{user.OfficerCode}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <td>{{user.Email}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Telephone</th>
                    <td>{{user.WorkPhone}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Fax Number</th>
                    <td>{{user.WorkFax}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Location Description</th>
                    <td>{{user.LocationDescription}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Mailstop / Banking Center #</th>
                    <td>{{user.Mailstop}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br>

            <h3 class="heading">User Applications</h3>
            <div style="border:3px solid #707070; padding-right:12px;">
                <h4 style="padding-left:5px;">User Applications</h4>
                <table id="Apps">
                    <tr id="AppsHeading">
                        <th>Application</th>
                        <th>User ID</th>
                        <th>Initial Password</th>
                        <th>Options / Comment</th>
                        <th>Setup Status</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="app in userApps[user.EmployeeID]">
                        <td>{{app.Application.Title}}</td>
                        <td>{{app.Title}}</td>
                        <td>{{app.InitialPassword}}</td>
                        <td>{{app.OptionsComments}}</td>
                        <td style="border-right:3px solid #707070;">{{app.SetupStatus}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```